# How to setup sqlite in c++ clr windowsform application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, clr, windowsformsintegration

I am working on a CRUD project in Visual Studio.
I have designed the form and completed all the functionality to show the entries in a listview.
Now I need to implement a local database to save the entries for future use. So I have selected sqlite. But unfortunately I am unable to do it and also there is no sufficient guides to solve this.

I don't have much knowledge of c++ and windowsform.

Can anyone please help me out giving an example how to setup it to call the sqlite functions from windowsform header file for CRUD operations

Comment: Try to  add reference:sqlite dll. Then add namspace: `Using namespace System::Data::SQLite`.

Comment: I was wire so build the same project in c#, I need to practice much more c++ programm